# GA utm_campaign "not set" and taken as utm_source

Tags: analytics, utm

In one of my email mkt that I send in a daily basis, the utm_parameters are defined as follows

```
www.mydomain.com{/page}#utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=textlink&utm_campaign=actividad
```

All the links are defined the same way, however when I see the statistics of campaigns, since 2 weeks ago it appears around 10% of the campaing with the following source/medium

```
Source / medium

newsletter&utm_medium=textlink&utm_campaign=actividad / (not set)
```

while the other 90% appear like this

```
Source / medium

newsletter / textlink
```

it looks like if in the first case, GA took the entire string as Source and nothing else as medium.

I have reviewed everything in the sources to check the links, and all of them are the same. I really do not know what to do.

I appreciate any help on this, since I'm about to surrender.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but looks like your syntax is not correct. `#` should be `?`:

Change This:

```
www.mydomain.com{/page}#utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=textlink&utm_campaign=actividad
```

To this:

```
www.mydomain.com{/page}?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=textlink&utm_campaign=actividad
```

Once you this is fixed GA should automatically sort your data into the right campaigns and also list your mediums.

Hope this works.